# Build Fail - TFS - Does not exist in XML namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, tfs, esri

I am having the error:

C:\Builds\16\Suite\Alliance G5 - Jessica\Sources\Source\CommonUI\Views\Maps\EsriMapView.xaml (24): The tag 'SimpleRenderer' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009'. Line 24 Position 18.

I have checked everything that I know to check. All the .dll(s) are being referenced and it runs locally. I only get that error when I am trying to Queue a build. Does anyone know what I might be missing? The log file did not tell me anything more than what the error message displayed. Code and Image are below.

XAML:

```
<inf:DialogWindowBase x:Class="Alliance.CommonUI.Views.Maps.EsriMapView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:map="clr-namespace:Alliance.Library.Maps;assembly=Alliance.Library"         
             xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009"
```

Line 24-28:
Note that any ESRI tag will cause this error, I have tried just taking out the Simple Renderer.

```
 <esri:SimpleRenderer x:Key="QueryRenderer">
            <esri:SimpleRenderer.Symbol>
                <esri:SimpleMarkerSymbol Color="Orange"/>
            </esri:SimpleRenderer.Symbol>
        </esri:SimpleRenderer>
```

[image: References]

It shows that it is checked out, but I assure you that the changes including those references have been checked in. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's the content of line 24?

Comment: Lines have been added :)

Comment: Note the difference between your `esri` and `map` namespace aliases - look at how `map` specifies a CLR namespace and assembly... I suspect you want to do the same thing for `esri`.

Comment: So would that make a difference when queuing a build vs just building from the solution?

Comment: It shouldn't, no. The DLL is definitely being picked up on the TFS side? Any other warnings before the error? (If it couldn't find the DLL, that might only trigger a warning rather than an error.)

Comment: Have you installed the latest ArcGIS SDK and its dependencies on the build server? It's probably missing a DLL on the TFS side.

Comment: @JonSkeet Honestly I am not sure... It is in my Solution Control Explorer, I am not extremely knowledgeable in how TFS handles references. I double checked the log and there are no warnings.

Comment: @Jamleck Didn't think of having to do that. Going to try installing it on the build server.

Comment: Ok. Let us know if that fixes it or not.

Comment: @Jamleck Installing it on the build server worked! Thank you so much for your help! If you want to post an answer with that solution, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally caused by the TFS build server missing referenced assemblies. To fix this, make sure you have installed any third party .dll references into your TFS build machine.

In this case, installing the ArcGIS SDK and its dependencies on the build server should fix the problem.